# UIActivitiindicatorView in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, sdcalertview

is there any way to add **UIActivityindicatorView** in **UIAlertView** like Loading?

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to modify or mess with the UIAlertView elements.  [If you look at Apple's documentation for UIAlertView, it says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
> and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
> private and must not be modified.

Better to do your own UIView and add an activity indicator view to that.

Answer (score 1):

Apple restrict the user the access the `subViews` of `UIAlertView` to maintain the UIAlertView interface standard on **IOS 7 release**.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you create your own view and use it instead of the UIAlertView one. There's no way of adding subviews to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not to UIAlertView, but take a look at [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView). It's a UIAlertView replica that does have support for displaying custom views.